# what is the diference between Time zone: Etc/UTC+05:30 (UTC, +0000) and UTC+05:30 of windows

Tags: linux, windows, time, timezone-offset

what is the difference between Etc/UTC+05:30 of linux machine and  UTC+05:30 of windows machine. are they same, if there is difference what is the differcne

Comment: UTC +hh:mm timezones are platform independent.

Comment: why i displays  Etc/UTC+05:30  in linux

Comment: That's an old name, not to be used: [Warning: Please do not use any of the timezones listed here (besides UTC)](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php)

Comment: I am setting timezone to UTC but it dispaying ETC/UTC _05:30

Comment: It sounds like it just displays the offset from UTC for your current timezone.

Answer (score 1):

Etc/UTC is the specified for the time zone whose display name is UTC. Check the IANA's time zone database.